# How to change iPhone App Binary file - on iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I want to know how can I change my binary on the itunes Connect page, When I press 'Upload binary' I don't get asked to upload an actual binary file.

I believe you need to Distribute using Organizer on Xcode and that creates the New version on iTunes Connect.

I updated Version 1.2 with metadata , but thats assigned to an older build.

Could someone confirm if thats correct? I Really dont want to have to add a new version.

Thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 1):

![enter image description here][1]Distributing through XCode does not create a new version.  You need to create a new version on iTunes Connect, and get it all the way through to the 'Waiting for Upload' stage (the last step will be clicking a button that says 'Ready to Upload Binary').  Once it's at that stage, and you distribute from XCode, the binary will be assigned to that version.

Don't worry about trying it out, if you don't have an app in iTunes Connect that's in the 'Waiting for Upload' stage, XCode will fail and let you know that it couldn't find a version with the correct status.

--- Screenshots below ---

[image: Encryption page]
[image: Final page]

Comment: My new version is in 'Prepare for Upload', I can't distribute to it, im just worried i have to upload a load of screenshots and translations again

Comment: Did you pass a step that asked if you added encryption to your app? There is a button you click that says you're ready to upload, it asks you that question, and then the status changes. I'll try and upload screenshots here in a bit.

Comment: After I select 'Ready to upload' I see the following question
Have you added or made changes to encryption features since you last uploaded a binary for this product?

Comment: Correct - and once you move past that step, it asks you if you want to automatically release once approved, or wait till you approve it.  I've added screenshots above.  Once you click on 'Save' on the second screen, your app status will change to 'Waiting for Upload'

Comment: Did you manage to get it to the upload status? Let me know if you need further help.